# Difference between map file and linker file

Tags: embedded, linker-scripts

What is the difference between the map file generated by the linker and the linker file that contains the memory segments itself ?

Comment: As far as I know they're the same. ("Linker Map File"). Do you mean the object-files generated by the compiler before linking?

Comment: hey thanks ,no I mean linker generates 2 files , 
the exe file and map file , I just dont know what is the use of the map file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 'linker' file is a set of commands to the linker as to how everything is to be laid out in memory and is created by the programmer.

The 'map' file is a listing of where everything is located in memory and is created by the linker.