# Difference between linker script file and .map file generated by linker?

Tags: embedded, linker-scripts

I understand that linker script file is an input to the linker, which contains memory layout and boundaries, and that the map file is an output of the linker process. But how does the map file differ from the linker script?
I'm talking about C linking here.
Note: I know that this [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614377/difference-between-map-file-and-linker-file), but it doesn't really answer/convince me.

Comment: Keep in mind, asking exact duplicate questions is typically not well-received here, even if you disclose your knowledge of the duplicate question. If you want a better answer, the correct thing to do is to post a bounty on the existing question once you have enough reputation. Alternatively, you could post a comment on that answer requesting clarification once you have enough reputation.

Comment: Okay thanks for your comment, sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 2):

The linker script is where you tell the linker where you want everything placed. The map file is how it ended up, given the restrictions of the linker script.

For example, if you want some large `const` table to sit in `.rodata` somewhere in flash, but somehow messed up the linking so that it ended up in RAM instead, the map file will tell you as much. So it is healthy practice to peek at the map file now and then, to make sure all your memory stays in line :)

Also, since the map file provides great detail of how much memory everything consumes, it is the first place to check when you need to perform memory optimizations.